# How to make regular expression not to display number in textBox in mvc 4 razor?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, textbox

I need to create a textBox where user fills in data (number of kids). The number of kids must be between 0 - 5.

Im using a regular expression, but the problem is, that when i run it in either firefox, chrome or IE, the default value of "0" displays in the textBox and the field isn't set to required because of the default number that displays in my textBox.

Why does this happen and what should i change about it?

**My code**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required entry!")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-5]{1,1}$", ErrorMessage="Number of kids must be between 0 and 5!")]
    public int Kids { get; set; }
```

---

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kids, "Number of kids:")
                <br />
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kids)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kids)
```

Comment: Your code works as is for me. No "0" is displayed in the textbox.

Comment: @mikhairu, a friend of mine gave me his code. He gets no "0" displayed in the textBox, but i do. Same happened when i gave him my code. He got no "0" displayed, but i do. I have exactly no idea how's that possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a nullable int instead (public int? Kids).  This way the default value will be null.

Fernando.

Comment: it works, but now when i type in the actual number of kids, data doesn't save and it gives me empty textbox after clicking "save data"